# AWS EC2 instance "This site can't be reached", though I do have the ports 80 and 443 open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been looking for help with this problem, and the answers just say to add inbound rules to the security group. Well, I have done those and I am still unable to access my website from the public DNS (just putting that into the url box and navigating to it). There are multiple port 22 inbound rules for the people accessing my server, and the outbound rule is just "All traffic".

Comment: Is there some sort of web server software actually installed and running on the EC2 server that is listening on ports 80 and 443?

Comment: I don't believe there is, I am just running a Flask (Python) website. Is there a way I can check if my server is occupying ports 80 and 443?

Comment: What ports have you configured Flask to listen on?

Comment: When I start up the Flask server (with `flask run`), it announces that it is "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/". To my knowledge I haven't configured it to listen on a specific port, I thought that I/a web user would be the ones "listening", or rather accessing it through a web browser.

Comment: So you would have to open port `5000` in the security group, and specify port `5000` in the URL you type into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem running Wordpress on EC2 instances. Things I'd try:

1. Access the instance via ssh. Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html
2. If you're accessing through ssh, maybe it's because your disk is full. To check this you can run `df -h` on your Amazon EC2 server.

Comment: MarkB got to the root of the issue in the comments on the original question - they had the webserver running on port 5000 by default, which wasnt open on the SG.

Answer (score 0):

I tried accessing my newly setup AWS EC2 Instance and I had this same issue, I later realised I was accessing the public DNS via HTTPS which had not been set up. when I changed the url to use HTTP it worked. Ensure to configure HTTP in the security group.